# Extracting part of a string between two known texts?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pull some numbers in a longer string. Strings vary in length but the numbers in all start after "ABC" and end with "DEF".

```vb
Dim strTemp, strFinal, Str1, Str2

strTemp = ActiveCell.Value
For J = 1 To Len(strTemp)
    For K = 1 To Len(strTemp)
        Str1 = Mid(strTemp, J, J + 2)
        Str2 = Mid(strTemp, K, K + 2)
        If ((StrComp(Str1, "ABC", vbTextCompare)) = 0) And ((StrComp(Str2, "DEF", vbTextCompare)) = 0) Then
            strFinal = Mid(strTemp, J + 4, K - 1)

    Next K
Next J
```

I'm thinking to do nested for loops, each looking for three characters in succession, and if they match the specific text, print everything in between.

The error says

> "next without for"

**Even though this is VBA, I'm quite sure I'm missing something in terms of sequence ordering/loop logic.**
Functions and syntax may be different but I'll take any other suggestions on how to do/loop it.

Comment: Nothing to do with Java

Comment: You are missing an `End If` **or** `strFinal = Mid(strTemp, J + 4, K - 1)` needs to be on same line as `then`. When you obviously have a loop and get this message it means there is an error after `for` and before the `next` statement somewhere.

Comment: I would split the `string` on *ABC*, do a `for - each` on each element and split on *DEF* and see if B(0) can be `CNum`ed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is made to extract matches.

### Code

```
Function getNumbersAfterPrefix(Text As String, RemovePrefix As Boolean, IgnoreCase As Boolean, ParamArray Prefixes() As Variant) As Collection
    Dim RegEx As Object, Matches As Object, Match As Object
    
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Dim Collection As New Collection
    
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        
        Dim n As Long
    
        For n = 0 To UBound(Prefixes)
            .Pattern = Prefixes(n) & "[\d]*"
            If .Test(Text) Then
                Set Matches = .Execute(Text)
                
                For Each Match In Matches
                    If RemovePrefix Then
                        Collection.Add Right(Match.Value, Len(Match.Value) - Len(Prefixes(n)))
                    Else
                        Collection.Add Match.Value
                    End If
                Next
            
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Set getNumbersAfterPrefix = Collection
End Function
```

### Test

```
Sub Test()
    Dim CollectionWithPrefix As New Collection
    Set CollectionWithPrefix = getNumbersAfterPrefix("ABC1324DEF234xyz", False, True, "ABC", "DEF")
    Dim CollectionWithOutPrefix As New Collection
    
    Set CollectionWithOutPrefix = getNumbersAfterPrefix("ABC1324DEF234", True, True, "ABC", "DEF")
    
    Stop
End Sub
```

### Test Result

[image: Test Result]